# Cocoa: Quartz, Core Graphics, Context vs View. Oh My!

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

Heads starting to hurt. I think I dropped into this too fast... Perhaps someone could help me visualize how these (excluding OpenGL ES) high level drawing libraries fit together - or point me to some high level docs. For example I see "context" and "view" used interchangeably in some cases but a view has one (only one?) context while a context doesn't have a view?!?

Nothing too elaborate just need help visualizing their differences and their boundaries (when to use one as opposed to the other).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a document with a graphic showing the relationship between these technologies, and an explanation of contexts:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185

It's under the "Core Image Programming Guide" overview if the link breaks again.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage

Comment: Interesting how/why Apple removed Figure 1-1 from that document in the updated (2009-05-18) version of the docs that ship with 3.0. And specifically this line: "Quartz 2D is implemented in the Core Graphics framework, a part of the Application Services umbrella framework." Makes it a little easier to see where Quartz 'lives' in relation to some of the other library/frameworks.

Comment: Just reviewed this question and realize Apple has removed the link. If anyone finds it again please update this!

Comment: Um, but that's about Core Image. It has nothing to do with Core Graphics, and the image (I have a copy) doesn't include Cocoa.

Comment: Yes, the link is about Core Image, but there is a figure (Figure 1-1) that shows Core Graphics in relation to other imaging technologies: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/art/graphics_arch.gif

That same figure isn't in the Core Graphics tech overview page.

Comment: All dead links :(

Comment: Updated the broken link again, also I added a new shorter link that hopefully won't change: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage